# Is it possible to disable navigation in libraries?

Tags: jetbrains-ide

I use PyCharm, Goland and WebStorm as IDEs for my (amateur) development.

When debugging or analyzing code I sometimes land in libraries sources, something I am not interested in. Typical when stepping over code I would like to stay within my own code in my project.

Is there a way to configure the IDEs to not step into library code?

Comment: You can follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-5085 to add this feature in GoLand.

Comment: For JavaScript debugger, there is **Do not step into library scripts** option (**Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Stepping**)